# My project don't work because of Flutter image

Tags: flutter, path, assets, flutter-image, pubspec

I have been trying to fix it, but I cannot add an image. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

I have trying to change path part but it didn't work.

maindart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dashboard.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'my flutter app',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DashBoard(),
    );
  }
}
```

dashboard:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DashBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashBoard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Image.asset(
          "ghibli.jpg",
          width: 300,
          height: 400,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using `Image.assets` which mean, you need to add the image to your assets on `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting into the question as text please? Images of text are harder to work with for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your image path to the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/ghibli.jpg
```

then use it like:

```
body: Image.asset(
    "images/ghibli.jpg",
     width: 300,
     height: 400,
  ));
```

Comment: it works thanks to  Image.asset(
    "images/ghibli.jpg", thank you so muchhhhh